# Get content of HTTPS GET request in Android

Tags: android, ssl, https, get, request

I have the following code which takes a normal HTTP GET Request and returns the output html as a string.

```
public static String getURLContent(String URL){
        String Result = "";
        String IP = "http://localhost/";
        try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL(IP.concat(URL));

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
                Result = Result+str+"~";
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

I would like to implement the same sort of thing for an unsigned ssl certificate but I am a bit of a novice at Java or Android programming and find some previous responses to similar questions very confusing.

Could someone change the code above to work with HTTPS requests?

One other question, would there be a risk of a middle-man-attack if I sent unencrypyted data via the GET request and print out database entries onto the webpage that the function returns the content of. Would it be better to use a POST request?

The reason I chose to use SSL is because someone told me that the data sent is encrypted. The data is sensitive and if I send something like localhost/login.php?user=jim&password=sd7vbsksd8 which would return "user=jim permission=admin age=23" which is data that I don't want others to see if they simply used a browser and sent the same request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
public class TestHttpGet {
    public void executeHttpGet() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI("http://w3mentor.com/"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();
            String page = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(page);
            } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can add parameters to an HTTP Get request as

```
HttpGet method = new HttpGet("http://w3mentor.com/download.aspx?key=valueGoesHere");
client.execute(method);
```

Android should automatically work with ssl. Maybe ssl certificate you are using on localhost is not trusted? Check this: [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

Check if you are able to browse https://yourhost/login.php?user=jim&password=sd7vbsksd8 using your browser.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick when I used the link you provided.